# Angular 4 : Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, viewchild

I am trying to click an accordion manually when a component gets loaded .But in my case I got the console error as I mentioned in the title and the accordion also not get clicked .

accordion :

```
<div class="accordion col-sm-12" id="accordion1" *ngFor='let data of dropdownData; let i=index'>
    <div class="accordion-group">

        <div class="accordion-heading">
            <a class="accordion-toggle h6" data-toggle="collapse"    data-parent="#accordion1" href="#collapseTwo + i" #accordion>
                {{data?.CAMD_ENTITY_DESC}}
            </a>
        </div>

        <div *ngFor='let group of data.group; let j=index' id="collapseTwo + i" class="accordion-body collapse"
         style="margin-left:10px">
            <div class="accordion-inner">
                <div class="accordion" id="accordion2">
                    <div class="accordion-group">

                        <div class="accordion-heading">
                            <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion2" [href]="'#collapseInnerTwo' + j">
                                {{group?.CAMD_PRGRP_DESC}}
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div [id]="'collapseInnerTwo' + j" class="accordion-body collapse" style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:3px">

                            <div class="accordion-inner" *ngFor='let subgroup of group?.subgroup; let i=index'>
                                {{subgroup?.CAMD_PRSGRP_DESC}}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here I have given **#accordion** to get the elementRef.

component

```
export class TwoComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
  dropdownData: any;
  id: number = 0;

  @ViewChildren('accordion') a: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private CartdataService: CartdataServiceService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.CartdataService.get_New_Products().subscribe(
      data => {
        this.dropdownData = data;
      });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.a.changes.subscribe(() => {
      let elementRef = this.a.toArray()[this.id];
      $(elementRef.nativeElement).trigger("click");
    });
  }

}
```

Can anyone help me to fix this issue .

Answer (score 1):

If you want trigger click without clicking you have use nativeElement.click

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.a.changes.subscribe(() => {
      let elementRef = this.a.toArray()[this.id];
       this.a.nativeElement.click;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: are you trying to target any specific element?

Comment: I am just trying to click a  an accordion by using it's index position @Chellappan

Comment: Okay @Chellappan

Comment: The same code I posted here is working in stackblitz but not in my project please help me to solve this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-4wyrd5?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts @Chellappan

Comment: in your project what error are you getting now? so you are using jquery to trigger the function?

Comment: I have 2 components ,got this error when I navigate from first component to second component @Chellappan

Comment: The thing is I have the same accordion in my both components ,what I am trying is assume I have 3 accordions in 1st component ,If I clicked On 2 nd accordion in first component I want to open the accordion in  2nd component after the component loads(here the clicked index position is passed from 1st component to second using service file ) @Chellappan

Comment: so can you add that second component also in the stackblitz.com

Comment: I checked it in stackblitz using two component there also it's working ,I got this error only in my project @Chellappan https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-bootstrap-carousel-dynamic2-k3egrl?file=app%2Ftwo%2Ftwo.component.ts

Comment: did you add jquery with typings?and if you use href to navigate in angular application it will show error

Comment: Yes I have @Chellappan

Comment: should avoid jquery in angular application since angular it's self is made for dom manipulation. instead of this approach use any third party library like angular material or ng bootstrap to implement accordion

Comment: please check the index file of this ,I have the following thins in my project https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rten9p?file=src%2Findex.html

Comment: why are you using jquery to submit form and everything

Comment: forms are using in 3 rd component ,hope that is not reason for this error @Chellappan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176101/discussion-between-chellappan-and-zhu).